# How to achieve website menu structure on google page in ASP.NET MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display my website menus such as below image once any one search for it on google (my Website : https://www.pawnalakepoint.in/). Can anyone help me how to achieve this using ASP.NET MVC 5 and C# ?

[image]

Comment: Is this what you mean?  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/search-result-features#expandable-2

Comment: yes , i  think it look like same , they have given search text box as well.